Opened question about pg_dump/pg_restore behaviour when (not) specifying database schema
recently, I  had to dump a postgresql database by doing:
pg_dump --format=custom --compress=6 --blobs --database mydb --schema public ... -f dump.bin

this generates a binary dump file, that I convert, for manual inspection, to the plain format:
pg_restore -f - dump.bin > dump.sql

dump.sql (output truncated):
-- PostgreSQL database dump

--
-- Dumped from database version 11.22

-- Dumped by pg_dump version 14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;

SET lock_timeout = 0;

SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;

SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';

SET standard_conforming_strings = on;

SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);

SET check_function_bodies = false;

SET xmloption = content;

SET client_min_messages = warning;

SET row_security = off;

--

-- Name: public; Type: SCHEMA; Schema: -; Owner: superuser

--

CREATE SCHEMA public;

ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO superuser;

--

-- Name: SCHEMA public; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: superuser

--

COMMENT ON SCHEMA public IS 'standard public schema';

At this point,
pg_restore -l dump.bin

gives (output truncated):
;

; Archive created at 2024-07-22 08:00:00 UTC
;     dbname: credit-decision
;     TOC Entries: 481
;     Compression: 6
;     Dump Version: 1.14-0
;     Format: CUSTOM
;     Integer: 4 bytes
;     Offset: 8 bytes
;     Dumped from database version: 11.22
;     Dumped by pg_dump version: 14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)


; Selected TOC Entries:

;

6; 2615 2200 SCHEMA - public superuser

5031; 0 0 COMMENT - SCHEMA public superuser

Now, when restoring by doing:
pg_restore --verbose --clean --if-exists --database mydb ... dump.bin

I get two warnings:
pg_restore: dropping SCHEMA public
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 6; 2615 2200 SCHEMA public superuser
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  cannot drop schema public because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  extension pg_stat_statements depends on schema public
extension pg_buffercache depends on schema public
extension unaccent depends on schema public
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
Command was: DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS public;
pg_restore: creating SCHEMA "public"
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "public" already exists
Command was: CREATE SCHEMA public;

It seems that toc entry 6 is responsible for the harmless warnings, that failure is somewhat expected.
Q1) I am wondering, if this toc entry 6 is somehow correlated to the "CREATE SCHEMA public" statement present at the beginning of the dump file ?
Second test, I am now dumping the same database but without specifying any schema option.
As a result:

the "CREATE SCHEMA public" statement has disappeared from the dump file.

the "CREATE EXTENSION unaccent" statement has appeared.

from the new TOC entries, none is referenced as "operating" on the public schema.


Finaly, when restoring with same options as previously, I get absolutely no warning. All went fine.
I would have expected, in the pg_restore output, an indication that the public schema was dropped (due to the usage of the --clean option).
The last trace of a dropping statement in this ouput is:
pg_restore: dropping EXTENSION unaccent

Then it starts recreating all objects which implies that the schema already exists...
It seems that pg_restore is clever enough not to drop/recreate the schema when dealing with extensions defined outside the schema itself but which remain dependant on it.
Q2) Is my last assumption correct ?
PS: I tried to be as descriptive as possible but probably too much.
